# log4j: show only INFO (not DEBUG) in my log file

Tags: java, netbeans, log4j

I was able to get log4j set up and running on NetBeans. I understand the chain of priority in the levels and right now this is my properties file config

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=F:\\log4j-applicationWS1.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

I want to print pure `INFO` to the `console` and my `log file`?
How could I do that?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. I created a new NetBeans project, added log4j-1.2.17 as dependency, the log4j.properties as shown above and from a small main method tried to write out `info()`, `debug()` and `warn()` messages. The output contained messages from `info()` and from `warn()`

Comment: the priority of the warn is higher than the info , so the warn messages also printed to the console as well , i don't know how to skip the warn messages

Answer (score 1):

What your are looking for is the [`LevelRangeFilter`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/varia/LevelRangeFilter.html):

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L -- %m%n
log4j.appender.stdout.filter.a=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter
log4j.appender.stdout.filter.a.levelMin=INFO
log4j.appender.stdout.filter.a.levelMax=INFO
log4j.appender.stdout.filter.a.acceptOnMatch=true

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=log4j-applicationWS1.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L -- %m%n
```